# tensorflow binary_crossentropy gives unexpected(possibly wrong) results

Tags: tensorflow, cross-entropy

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
K.binary_crossentropy([[0.0],[1.0]],[[1.0],[0.0]], from_logits=False)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[15.333239],
       [15.424949]], dtype=float32)>
```

Now in theory, crossentropy isn't symmetric but when looking at the implementation of binary_crossentropy, crossentropy(0,1) and crossentropy(1,0) should yield the same result.

In https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4825C67-L4825C67

```
epsilon_ = _constant_to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)

bce = target * math_ops.log(output + epsilon())
bce += (1 - target) * math_ops.log(1 - output + epsilon())
return -bce
```

epsilon is defined as 1e-7, so when target==1, output==0, you get ln(2e-7)==15.424949, but target==0, output==1 also yield ln(2e-7) when plugging in the numbers. Where does 15.333239 come from?